# PHP - 2 pages with same content but with different tags

Tags: php, html, seo

I am dabbling with PHP, Wordpress and some HTML5. I have made 3 files; news, news-IE and news-HTML5. News checks the browser type and grabs news-IE (divs) or news-HTML5 (HTML5 tags) depending on if the browser is IE8 or later. Is this a bad way to do this? Will this cause search engines to mark as duplicate content? If so, a disallow should be added to the robots.txt I assume, right?

Code:

```
<?php 
   $IE; 
   if( strstr('/(?i)msie [1-8]/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ) { $IE = 't'; } else { $IE = 'f'; } 
?>
<?php 
   if( $IE == 't' ) { get_template_part("news-IE"); } else { get_template_part("news-HTML5"); }
```

?>

note: I am just playing with this method due to progressive enhancement being discussed in the work place. I thought maybe this would be an ok solution to Javascript being disabled in IE that way, divs will take place of, say, a section tag.

Comment: I don't know of any scrapers that matter which send an MSIE header. I think you're safe doing that, even it it isn't the best technique. You could also just use a regex like `/\bsection\b/` to find/replace any section tags with a DIV, etc.

Comment: @RobertK - thanks for your reply and tip. I am going to look up how to find and replace.

Comment: On second thought, the pattern I gave would also replace every word "section" with "div" if you used it. You can always replace `<section` with `<div` with [`str_replace()`](http://php.net/str_replace).

Comment: @RobertK Is there any chance you can display an example? If not, that is cool, I will keep searching. I am newish to php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignoring the code in general, the search engines will only read news, not news-IE or news-HTML5. You can make sure of this by adding a robots.txt file to your root directory, and making sure that you set a disallow for the specific files, for instance if they are all in your root directory you could do:

```
disallow: /news-HTML5.html
disallow: /news-IE.html
```

Replacing .html with whatever file extensions you have for those files.

Comment: thanks for you input but don't I need at least one of the pages to be allowed so the bot can read the content? Does news already contain the correct content, depending on browser, and then the bot crawls it?

Comment: If you're using the two pages as includes, than you don't need the bot to crawl them, as it will crawl news.php. The bot will load the content of one of the pages, whichever you choose to let it see first. Because PHP is a server-side language, the content is put together on the server, and shown to the bot afterwards.

Comment: As a follow up to this, as it's just now occurred to me, you could also save both files as .php and at the top include an if block that checks to see if the page is news.php, and if not it performs a permanent redirect to news.php, thus avoiding any chance of duplicate content issues.